# Ruby on Rails: How do I submit a form of checkboxes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an object: @object 
with tons of boolean fields.

now. according to the HTML spec, if a checkbox isn't checked, the value isn't sent.

Which is a problem... cause I need that information.

How do I get around that?  the api for f.check_box suggests fields_for... http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M002298

but I couldn't figure out the syntax for @object.is_admin

=\

currently, without changing anything: i have this:

```
<% form_for @object do |f| %>
        <td><%= f.check_box :allow_downloads, :label => false  %></td>
.
.
.
```

error : `undefined method`to_i' for #`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my was accessing the wrong controller. I moved my form to a proper view (made more sense for usability, anyway) and it works.

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing you should be concerned about.

If you look at the check_box helper generated code you'll see that rails creates a hidden field which represents the unchecked value.
When you check the box, it will take precedence over the hidden field, because it's declared after it:

```
<input type="hidden" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the automatically generated hidden fields for the checkboxes as described by that documentation not working for you?

Comment: added some code to my post. the page renders nothing but the error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no '=' in the `<% f.check_box`. It should be `<%= f.chec_box...`

besides, if all fields are boolean, you can set them all to false, and only set true the ones passed through the request.

Comment: aye, i noticed that... but that has nothing to do with my undefined methodto_i' error

Comment: well, in the bit of code you put there, there is not even a '#' symbol, I can't say what's wrong without seeing at at least the form :]
probably it is a typo or something not being closed.